# Get DRF token from python-social-auth backend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I am trying to integrate Social Authentication in my DRF backend. I decided to go with [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth). If I serve my social login through Django (and an HTML view), I can see my login in successful. I also figured that I can redirect after successful social authentication as outlined [here](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#return-the-user-to-the-original-page).

Until now, my frontend (a Nuxt app) was using [DRF tokens](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication). Even though:

1. I can create valid tokens for social accounts.
2. My frontend can redirect the users to -> complete authorization with OAuth sites e.g. Google, Twitter -> return back to the frontend.

Is it possible for me to somehow manage to redirect a successfully authenticated user to the frontend **with the associated and valid DRF token** as a query parameter?

Answer (score 3):

You can, it's not trivial, tho. It's possible because the mechanism to retrieve URLs (success or errors ones) is delegated to [strategies `setting()` method](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/eeee9763862d768627e134a42e4664456b6eabec/social_core/strategy.py#L42-L51), which in the end invokes [`get_setting()` on final implementations](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/b6e791adf96c3f13c3e499669e50093f8dc23461/social_django/strategy.py#L40-L47). This method you can override to add your custom logic.

These steps should get you on the road:

1. Define a custom strategy

   ```py
   from social_django.strategy import DjangoStrategy


   class CustomStrategy(DjangoStrategy):
       def get_setting(self, name):
           if name == 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL':
               token = get_drf_token()
               return f'/?toke={token}'
            else:
                return super().get_setting(name)
   ```
2. Point your `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY` settings to this new strategy (import path syntax)

Comment: Hmm, there's no setting with the name `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, therefore the path is never hit.

Comment: You can define the setting yourself with the desired value

Comment: I tried, but I am still clueless. I was thinking there would be some final `redirect` function in the strategy which I can override. Do you have any further pointers?

Comment: The redirect is handled by the common [`do_complete()` action](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/eeee9763862d768627e134a42e4664456b6eabec/social_core/actions.py#L58-L90), do you happen to have `NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL` or `NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL` settings defined?

Comment: Thanks a lot! No, I have none of those defined.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Sadly the only option I have left is to turn `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` back on :/

Comment: Could you try to debug that section I've linked (on `do_complete()`)? It will give point you on what condition your user is landing on and from there you can infer the setting used to pull the redirect value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232422/discussion-between-daveidito-and-omab).

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a custom strategy, which I believe is more the library's style, there is another explicit solution:

Since `python-social-auth` allows redirection after successful authentication, open another endpoint that will a. generate a token b. redirect to the frontend. So I defined follow `api_view`:

```py
@api_view(http_method_names=['get'])
def user_token(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        token, e = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        return redirect('<front-end>/?token='+token.key)
    else:
        return redirect(`<front-end>/login/?error=true')
```

Now a potential authentication flow is like this:

User visits front-end -> Click 'login using Github et.al.' -> Login at the third party (say, Github) -> Back to backend `/success/` -> redirect to front-end url (based on the above view) with the token -> Handle the query parameter on the frontend (which is pretty trivial in my case where I am using Nuxt).

If we mount `user_token` at path `/success/token/`, then once the user visits: `http:<backend>:/login/github/?next=/success/token/`, every right step on users part will take him/her to the front-end with the query param `token` set as the right token.

UPDATE: This will only work if DRF has session authentication active, otherwise `request.user.is_authenticated` can never be true.

Comment: This way the token ends up in the browser history (?)